# OS X Carbon framework on 64bit system

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

I am trying to create a window using Carbon framework in C++ on Mac OS X Maverick.I need it to setup AGL window OpenGL context.But what I found is that most of related Carbon methods link only in x86 mode.For example in the header for 'CreateNewWindow' method it is clearly stated :

> Availability:  *    Mac OS X:         in version 10.0 and later in
>   Carbon.framework [32-bit only]

So I succeed compiling it only in 32bit mode which is useless to me as I target 64bit OS.What's the workaround for 64bit? Also I am not interested in using Cocoa + ObjectiveC way of doing it.

Comment: 32 bit apps run just fine on 64 bit OS X. The only problem is if your app needs a large amount of memory (> 2 GB).

Comment: My bad explantion - the app which I target is 64bit and it doesn't run plugins published as 32bit.

Comment: OK - time to ditch Carbon then - Apple has been warning developers about this for about 10 years now.

Comment: @PaulR I am Apple developer since a couple of month ago ;) So how do I work around this?With Cocoa?Is there C/C++ API for creating the window?I see only Obj-C examples everywhere.

Comment: Yes, Carbon has been deprecated for a very long time, which is why it was never completely transitioned to 64 bit. Check the architecture(s) of your app with `lipo` though - it may be a "fat" app with 32 bit and 64 bit executables, in which case you can force it to launch as a 32 bit app. In the long run though you should probably forget about Carbon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned, Carbon is no longer supported in 64-bit mode. You need to create a Cocoa app. The easiest way to do what you want is to create an `NSWindow` containing an [`NSOpenGLView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenGLView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Also, AGL is deprecated. The context you get from an `NSOpenGLView` will be a `CGLContext`.

<strike>It sounds like you're trying to make some old code work. You should also read up on OpenGL 3.3 and later. If you're using OpenGL code that worked with Carbon, it's likely OpenGL 1.2 and using lots of deprecated functionality.</strike>

Comment: Nope.This is pretty fresh code I wrote several months ago targeting OpenGL 3.2 (programmable) API on Lion OS.What has changed is that when I upgraded to Maverick OpenGL context created without windows started crushing when using default framebuffer.So now I need to create a window based context to have default FBO created.At least that's what I beleive should be done.

Comment: OK, then I'll remove the second half of my answer, but the first half is still valid.

Comment: Carbon actually still works for 64-bit applications, just not all parts of it. In particular, anything related to windowing is unavailable.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman does this mean that a 32bit application would still be able to use windowing features, or has the support been entirely removed?

Comment: @ShaunWilson: I cannot comment on the current state of OS X, I haven't used it in quite a while :-\ However, when that comment was written the situation was that 64-bit Carbon lacked support for window message loops and so forth. A 32-bit application could use Carbon in its entirety, which allows you to use AGL for windowed rendering. Apple wants you to use Cocoa for all user interactive stuff and it's a good idea to spend a little bit of time writing a wrapper around the Objective C classes that Cocoa uses. They're the only thing Apple intends to support moving forward.