# Mac OSX Sierra CoreFoundation/CoreServices/CoreGraphics not working

Tags: c++, c, macos, frameworks, core-foundation

When I try to compile anything which includes CoreFoundation, CoreServices or CoreGraphics, e.g Carbon, I get the following error message.

```
gcc x.c -framework Carbon
In file included from /usr/include/Availability.h:180:0,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/lib/gcc/6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0/6.2.0/include-fixed/math.h:46,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:24,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:19,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Headers/Carbon.h:20,
                 from x.c:1:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDateFormatter.h:53:34: error: 'introduced' undeclared here (not in a function)
     kCFISO8601DateFormatWithYear API_AVAILABLE(macosx(10.12), ios(10.0), watchos(3.0), tvos(10.0)) = (1UL << 0),
                                  ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFURL.h:777:39: error: 'deprecated' undeclared here (not in a function)
 const CFStringRef kCFURLLabelColorKey API_DEPRECATED("Use NSURLLabelColorKey", macosx(10.6, 10.12), ios(4.0, 10.0), watchos(2.0, 3.0), tvos(9.0, 10.0));
                                       ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFURL.h:777:39: error: 'message' undeclared here (not in a function)
 const CFStringRef kCFURLLabelColorKey API_DEPRECATED("Use NSURLLabelColorKey", macosx(10.6, 10.12), ios(4.0, 10.0), watchos(2.0, 3.0), tvos(9.0, 10.0));
                                       ^
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/Security.h:81:0,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Headers/CSIdentity.h:43,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Headers/OSServices.h:27,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Headers/IconsCore.h:23,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Headers/LaunchServices.h:22,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:39,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Headers/Carbon.h:20,
                 from x.c:1:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/Authorization.h:194:7: error: variably modified 'bytes' at file scope
  char bytes[kAuthorizationExternalFormLength];
       ^~~~~
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGContext.h:18:0,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGBitmapContext.h:9,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CoreGraphics.h:11,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Headers/ApplicationServices.h:35,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Headers/Carbon.h:24,
                 from x.c:1:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGFont.h:53:40: error: initializer element is not constant
 static const CGFontIndex kCGGlyphMax = kCGFontIndexMax;
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be? I am not sure if this started after updating to macOS Sierra or Xcode to version 8.1. Edit: The program seems to compile in Xcode, but not in terminal with homebrew gcc 6.2.

Answer (score 2):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630337/os-x-carbon-framework-on-64bit-system), Carbon has long been deprecated. However, you might try AppKit:

```
gcc x.c -framework AppKit
```

For me it works fine when I write pure-C apps for OS X.

[EDIT:] Now the code.

```
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    while (!CGEventSourceKeyState(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState, 0x7E))
        usleep(10000);
    return 0;
}
```

This app only depends on AppKit and loops until up arrow (scan code `0x7E`) is pressed.

Here`s the full list of codes (not sure where they are in official headers): [Carbon's Virtual Key Codes](http://snipplr.com/view/42797/).

Comment: Does AppKit allow you to read the current global keyboard state, e.g if a key is KeyDown, without creating some sort of window? I create terminal applications and this is the only functionality I use it for.

Answer (score 1):

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFDateFormatter.h:53:34: error: 'introduced' undeclared here (not in a function)
     kCFISO8601DateFormatWithYear API_AVAILABLE(macosx(10.12), ios(10.0), watchos(3.0), tvos(10.0)) = (1UL << 0),`

IMHO it's just that this header is not supported by gcc-6.2 but only by clang. Maybe it will be "fixed" with gcc-7.

A similar problem exists with gcc-5.x and El Capitan (sdk 10.11) where gcc-6.x is needed in order to build with the Apple headers like this one.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this with "Core-Foundation" but the availability macros you're talking about (described more in detail in the first couple paragraphs of the [Foundation Release Notes for macOS 10.12 & iOS 10](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-Foundation-OSX10.12/) describe the API Availability Macros a bit more in detail.

I suspect you might need to simply include the Foundation framework in your build (to pick up these macros which CoreFoundation & CoreGraphics appear to depend on) and you should be okay going forward.

Comment: Ok, I will try it!

Comment: I tried to #include <Foundation/Foundation.h> in my c file and it brings up a whole lot of errors. I also tried to compile with -framework Foundation but it does not seem to help. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Robert.S yes. The main thing you\`re doing wrong now is trying to compile C with ObjC-only includes.